# Loop Syntax error in MS-DOS 6.22

Tags: loops, batch-file, dos, virtual-pc

I'm trying a script to get the last modified date on a virtual PC running MS DOS 6.22.
But whenever I find a solution which includes a loop, it shows syntax error in the console. 
Here's one of the lines that shows this :

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\log") do echo Modified date: %%~ta
```

Is dos 6.22 incompatible with the loops ? I have a lot of restrictions with this version (can't use robocopy, date, etc...)

Comment: Yes, the loop syntax is only available in Windows (NT 4.0 and later). It's not supported in MS-DOS. But why on earth are you using MS-DOS?

Comment: In this case, your only hope is `goto` ... hurts a lot to say that, but seems to be the only way. See this [book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=u7oN-5y7nGsC&pg=PA399&lpg=PA399&dq=loop+under+ms-dos+6.22&source=bl&ots=j5k43MOup0&sig=NQ_pGaFOG4UMx1NsooTo_upIOMw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Ozm-VM3oJs7daOOJgMgI&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=loop%20under%20ms-dos%206.22&f=false) for some examples ... and I deeply wish you good luck (I don't think it's your choice to work on this environment ...).

Comment: Just as a side question: MS-DOS is unsupported since `2001-12-31`. Why is this software/script still being developed in this legacy platform/OS?

Answer (score 1):

The loop syntax is supported, but a bit limited (see also `for /?`).

```
FOR %A in (filelist) do myCmd %%A
```

So there are no switches at all.

As I remember in the most cases it wasn't possible to catch data with DOS.
It was really hard stuff even to split a simple string.

But if you absolutly need it (or have fun with it) you can split a string with a `FOR` loop into the first character and the rest by

```
for %%A in (/%var%) do echo %%A
```

But to save the first character is a bit tricky...

Or you could use `edlin` or `debug` to *parse* strings.

Advanced stuff like request the last modified date of a file was behind the possibilities of ms-dos.

But why you don't try it from your host computer to access the *inner* file system of the VM?
Then you could also use all *modern* technologies like cmd.exe batch

Comment: Actually I need to collect data from WindTurbine, and the machine is running on this poor version of MS DOS, after a long time I could activate file sharing and copy some data. But I want to do it automatically, a 10 minutes routine, and I'm stuck at this point. This version is too limited.

Thank you for answering though :)